# Pinterest Create APP With PHP Curl Failed Problem

Tags: php, api, curl, pinterest

I want to create App Pinterest with PHP Curl but this is not working. The application I follow the POST process: Postman Interceptor

Request:

```
curl 'https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/' 
-H  'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0' 
-H  'Accept: */*' 
-H  'Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' --compressed 
-H  'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H  'X-CSRFToken: IjExYmYxYzZlZDgwM2RlMGQxNzEyZjdlZTRkZTk3NmQ0OTliZWQwYTki.XlzcOw.zET53I_suQKC2TbplvhpouiuaAM' 
-H  'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
-H  'Origin: https://developers.pinterest.com' 
-H  'DNT: 1' 
-H  'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H  'Referer: https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/' 
-H  'Cookie: _pinterest_sess=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; _auth=1; session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMTFiZjFjNmVkODAzZGUwZDE3MTJmN2VlNGRlOTc2ZDQ5OWJlZDBhOSJ9.XlzdMQ.qu4RJUJgbv0UygBZFyPjw6-aGkw; csrftoken=lwBLncs70zm1Y2Xhx9D7M6w6pVZQw6ro; _dev_sess=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; country-code=TR' 
-H  'TE: Trailers' --data '{"name":"test1","description":"test description"}'
```

Full Codes:

```
<?php
//preg_match('/csrftoken(.*?)[\b;\s]/i', $headers, $csrf_token);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$appname  = "deneme33";
$appdescription = "lorem ipsum deneme";
$username = "talithae.matson_53@hotmail.com";
$password = "SahsZGHx";

// this is the http post data for logging in - username & password are substituted in later
$login_post     = array(
        'source_url' => '/login/',
        'data' => '{"options":{"username_or_email":"%s","password":"%s"},"context":{}}',
        'module_path' => 'App()>LoginPage()>Login()>Button(class_name=primary, text=Log In, type=submit, size=large',
);
$create_app     = array(
    'data' => '{"name":"%s","description":"%s"}',
);
$pinterest_url  = 'https://www.pinterest.com/';  //'https://www.pinterest.com/'; // pinterest home url
$developer_url  = 'https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/';  // Developer home url
$login_url      = $pinterest_url . 'login/';     // pinterest login page url
$login_post_url = $pinterest_url . 'resource/UserSessionResource/create/'; // pinterest login post url

// http headers to send with requests
$httpheaders    = array(
       'Connection: keep-alive',
       'Pragma: no-cache',
       'Cache-Control: no-cache',
       'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
);

// http headers to send when logging in
$login_header   = array(
        'X-NEW-APP: 1',
        'X-APP-VERSION: 08930e3',  // THIS WILL UPDATE FREQUENTLY, CHANGE IT!!!
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01');
$developer_header   = array(
        'Accept: */*',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type: application/json');
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// request home page to establish cookies and a session, set curl options

$ch = curl_init($pinterest_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('debug.txt', 'w+'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheaders);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

sleep(5);
//echo "Giriş Datası".$data;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// parse the csrf token out of the cookies to set later when logging in
list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);

$headers = file_get_contents('cookie.txt', true);
//print_r($headers);
preg_match("/csrftoken+(.*?)\n/i",$headers,$matches);
$csrf_token=trim($matches[1]);
preg_match("/session+(.*?)\n/i",$headers,$matches);
$session=trim($matches[1]);
echo "Token:". $csrf_token.PHP_EOL;
echo "Session:". $session.PHP_EOL;
//die();
// next request the login page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);



//Developer Cookie Get
$ch = curl_init($developer_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('debug.txt', 'w+'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheaders);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//Developer Cookie Get





//Make APP
$create_app['data'] = sprintf($create_app['data'], $appname, $appdescription);
$post               = http_build_query($create_app);
print_r($post);
die();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $developer_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty",
    "X-CSRFToken: ".$csrf_token,
    "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Host: developers.pinterest.com",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Cookie: session=".$session,
    "Connection: keep-alive"
  ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//Make APP

//echo "Baş Header".print_r($developer_header);

echo $data;
die();


$login_header[] = 'X-CSRFToken: ' . $csrf_token;
$login_post['data'] = sprintf($login_post['data'], $username, $password);
$post               = http_build_query($login_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_merge($httpheaders, $login_header));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// perform login post    

//print_r($csrf_token);


// check response and output status

if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
    echo "Error logging in.<br />";
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
} else {
    $response = json_decode($data, true);

    if ($response === null) {
        echo "Failed to decode JSON response.<br /><br />";
        var_dump($response);
    } else if ($response['resource_response']['status'] === "success") {
        print_r($response['resource_response']);
        //print_r($response['resource_response']['data']);
        //print_r($response['resource_response']['username']);
        echo "Login successful, " . $response['resource_response']['user']['username'] . "<br /><br />";
        echo "You have {$response['resource_response']['data']['follower_count']} followers, are following {$response['resource_response']['data']['following_count']} users.  You have liked {$response['resource_response']['data']['like_count']} pins.";
    }
}
```

I think there is a problem with the data I sent after //Make APP.

Cookies: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu4VQ.jpg

Body: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LbXe.jpg

Headers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI1fR.jpg

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51oSB.jpg

I might be missing something during the post operation.

What am I missing in xhr post sending?

Comment: Pictures of text are nearly always problematic. If you can't provide the actual headers in the question itself, you can upload them to e.g. https://dpaste.com/ and link to that location.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to call is not part of their normal REST API it looks like. I believe you are supposed to [visit that manually](https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/) and create your app first. Then work with their API after that.

[Source](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/)

Did you find documentation from them that allows you to do that, or are you trying to hack a method together to accomplish it?

Comment: I know that the application creation section doesn't work with api.I want to automatically create applications for my accounts.If I can create an application, I will automatically create a token through these applications.I can access the developer section with Curl.I'm not sure I sent the xhr post data correctly in the section where the application will be created.

Comment: I was able to successfully make a call from postman using a copied curl command from the browser. You could try using this tool to generate PHP from a curl and compare https://tools.chilkat.io/curl.cshtml . I'm guessing might be missing a header or a token/cookie is expired.